# Unable to upload file through selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload a csv file to my application.

I am getting the following error:

> unknown error: cannot focus element   (Session info:
>   chrome=55.0.2883.87)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924
>   (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux
>   3.13.0-107-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 101 milliseconds

My code :

```
UtilsMethods.element = UtilsMethods.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dragandrophandler']"));
Thread.sleep(10);
UtilsMethods.element.sendKeys("/home/arima/wrangler_testdata/Telstra/test.csv");
```

html code :

```
<section class="wrangler-product-upload-connect z-depth-1">
<div class="row" style="margin-top:25px;">
<div class="col l12 m12 s12">
<div class="col l12 m12 s12" style="padding: 0px;">
<div class="upload-connect-content">
<div id="upload" class="col s12" style="display: block;">
<input id="fileupload" style="display:none" type="file"/>
<form class="file-uplaod-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="box-content center-align">
<div id="dragandrophandler" style="height:250px;">
<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"/>
<br/>
  Drag & Drop Files Here
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="test2" class="col s12" style="display: none;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Show some `HTML` code

Comment: Is path to the .csv file is correct?

Comment: yes the path is correct . I am using ubuntu .Is that the issue ?

Comment: @Andersson i have added the HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to send path to file to `div` element while you need to handle `<input type="file">`. Try below:

```
UtilsMethods.element = UtilsMethods.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fileupload']"));
Thread.sleep(10);
UtilsMethods.element.sendKeys("/home/arima/wrangler_testdata/Telstra/test.csv");
```